# updating label on button click tkinter/python

Tags: python, tkinter

What im trying to do is upon clicking the button, the label below it increases by one. Im honestly getting nowhere, as i change one thing and i get an error, i fix that error and i get another.

heres a sample of my code i've no idea what im doing wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

count1=0
count2=0
count3=0

    def vote(voting)
         voting.set +=1
         lbl1.set(text= count1)
         lbl2.set(text=count2)
         lbl3.set(text=count3)
 root = Tk()
 frame = ttk.Frame(root)
 b1 = ttk.Button(frame, text="v1", command=vote(count1))
 b1.grid(row=2,column=1)
 b2 = ttk.Button(frame, text="v2", command=vote(count2))
 b2.grid(row=2,column=2)
 b3 = ttk.Button(frame, text="v3", command=vote(count3))
 b3.grid(row=2,column=3)
 lbl1 = ttk.Label(frame, text=count1)
 lbl2 = ttk.Label(frame, text=count2)
 lbl3 = ttk.Label(frame, text=count3)
 lbl1.grid(row=3,column=1)
 lbl2.grid(row=3,column=2)
 lbl3.grid(row=3,column=3)
 frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please show the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the command argument must be a function, not the result of a function, so it can't have the `()` on it. If you must pass a parameter you need to make a helper function. You can do that dynamically with functools.partial or lambda, but in this case I think it's easier to simply make 3 helper functions the normal way.

Second, it would be a lot easier to use a IntVar, so the Label stays updated automatically. I think you wanted to do this anyway, since set() is a Variable method, not a Label method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def vote1():
    count1.set(count1.get() + 1)
def vote2():
    count2.set(count2.get() + 1)
def vote3():
    count3.set(count3.get() + 1)

root = Tk()
count1=IntVar()
count2=IntVar()
count3=IntVar()

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
b1 = ttk.Button(frame, text="v1", command=vote1)
b1.grid(row=2,column=1)
b2 = ttk.Button(frame, text="v2", command=vote2)
b2.grid(row=2,column=2)
b3 = ttk.Button(frame, text="v3", command=vote3)
b3.grid(row=2,column=3)
lbl1 = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=count1)
lbl2 = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=count2)
lbl3 = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=count3)
lbl1.grid(row=3,column=1)
lbl2.grid(row=3,column=2)
lbl3.grid(row=3,column=3)
frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
root.mainloop()
```

However this would be the ideal place for a subclass that bundles those things together in a new reusable widget.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Mick(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, text='', **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        self.var = IntVar()
        btn = ttk.Button(self, text=text, command=self.vote)
        btn.grid(row=0,column=0)
        lbl = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var)
        lbl.grid(row=1,column=0)

    def vote(self):
        self.var.set(self.var.get() + 1)

root = Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(root)
for i in range(4): # set number of voting boxes here
    b1 = Mick(frame, text='v'+str(i))
    b1.grid(row=0, column=i)
frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
root.mainloop()
```

Now you can easily scale it to make as many voting blocks as you want!

Comment: You're a legend, I had fiddled with IntVar trying to get this to work before but got nowhere. Thanks heaps!!